# How to configure Vim Ctrl-P to search for directory name and open default file?

Tags: vim

My current project file structure looks like this:

[image]

When I trigger CtrlP and start typing the file name "index.js" it will find too many results. And when I prefix the letters with the foldername then there are none.

How can I configure Vim CtrlP to search for directory name instead of file name and deliver as a result the index.js inside the directory (that's the default behavior in Atom's fuzzy finder)?

Apparently it's an issue of my vim ctrl-p configuration:

[ctrl-p doesn't match foldernames](https://i.imgur.com/OawhPIQ.mp4)

Comment: ctrlp does match against folder names. Be aware it's case sensitive by default.

Comment: `<Ctrl-P>Stoind` should do a perfectly good job of selecting `StorePicker/index.js` for instance

Comment: Ah ok, I suppose it's an issue of my configuration. I'll update my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, as Andy and hobbs noted, ctrl-p should match against foldernames.

In my config it was overwritten with:

```
" Default to filename searches - so that appctrl will find application
" controller
let g:ctrlp_by_filename = 1
```

By replacing 1 with 0, the default behavior of ctrl-p could be restored and it matches foldernames.